# How to declare a variable in SQL Server and use it in the same Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, local-variables

Im trying to get the value from BrandID in one table and add it to another table. But I can't get it to work. Anybody know how to do it right?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddBrand
AS

DECLARE 
@BrandName nvarchar(50),
@CategoryID int,
@BrandID int

SELECT @BrandID = BrandID FROM tblBrand 
WHERE BrandName = @BrandName

INSERT INTO tblBrandinCategory (CategoryID, BrandID) 
       VALUES (@CategoryID, @BrandID) 

RETURN
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I can see the following issues with that SP, which may or may not relate to your problem:

- You have an extraneous `)` after `@BrandName` in your `SELECT` (at the end)
- You're not setting `@CategoryID` or `@BrandName` to anything anywhere (they're local variables, but you don't assign values to them)

In a comment you've said that after fixing the `)` you get the error:

> Procedure AddBrand has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

That's telling you that you haven't declared any *parameters* for the SP, but you called it with parameters. Based on your reply about `@CategoryID`, I'm guessing you wanted it to be a parameter rather than a local variable. Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddBrand
   @BrandName nvarchar(50), -- These are the
   @CategoryID int          -- parameter declarations
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @BrandID int

   SELECT @BrandID = BrandID FROM tblBrand WHERE BrandName = @BrandName

   INSERT INTO tblBrandinCategory (CategoryID, BrandID) VALUES (@CategoryID, @BrandID)
END
```

You would then call this like this:

```
EXEC AddBrand 'Gucci', 23
```

or this:

```
EXEC AddBrand @BrandName = 'Gucci', @CategoryID = 23
```

...assuming the brand name was 'Gucci' and category ID was 23.

Comment: I get the following error: Procedure AddBrand has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

I Corrected the ")"

I dont know what you mean about the CategoryID, I have a value on my aspx page that I bring in to the SP and would like to add to tblBrandinCategory

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddBrand
@BrandName nvarchar(50) = null,
@CategoryID int = null
AS    
BEGIN

DECLARE @BrandID int = null
SELECT @BrandID = BrandID FROM tblBrand 
WHERE BrandName = @BrandName

INSERT INTO tblBrandinCategory (CategoryID, BrandID) 
       VALUES (@CategoryID, @BrandID)

END

EXEC AddBrand @BrandName = 'BMW', @CategoryId = 1
```

Comment: Are you sure this line is right?

"@CategoryID int = null,"

Seems like that last comma shouldn't be there...

Comment: Thanks blobbles, i have removed the comma

Answer (score 1):

In sql 2012 (and maybe as far back as 2005), you should do this:

```
EXEC AddBrand @BrandName = 'Gucci', @CategoryId = 23
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above methods worked for me so i'm posting the way i did

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE AddBrand()
BEGIN 

DECLARE BrandName varchar(50);
DECLARE CategoryID,BrandID  int;
SELECT BrandID = BrandID FROM tblBrand 
WHERE BrandName = BrandName;

INSERT INTO tblBrandinCategory (CategoryID, BrandID) 
       VALUES (CategoryID, BrandID);
END$$
```