# variable query ms excel

Tags: excel, db2, db2-400

Hello I am unable to find sources on how to set up a variable in a query in MS Excel. The " Declare @var, Set @var " is not working.. Please let me know how can I create a variable for the query below..

SELECT inv.idclient, inv.invnumber, inv.invdate

FROM source.invoices inv

WHERE
inv.idclient = 111222
AND  inv.invdate > d{'2014-01-01'}  --> I want this value to be replaced by a variable

This query is very simple, but I have ones where I have to put more than 10 times the same date...reason why I would like to create a variable.

Dont hesitate if you have questions.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions: 
1. using VBA. Let's say your query output starts in cell C1 and the date variable is stored in cell A1. If you're not very comfortable writing macros, then it would be easiest to record a macro first to capture the connection string, etc. To do that, go to Developer -> Record Macro and while it's recording, click anywhere in your table (C1 using my assumptions), go to Design -> Properties. In the window that opens up, click on the property icon (next to the Name: dbName box). In the window that follows, click on the Definition tab and make a change (any simple change will do) to the query. This will record what's needed for the VBA code. Now click "ok" and "ok" again to get out of thos windows, stop macro recording and go to VBA (one way is to right click on the sheet name -> View code) and find your new code (if it's the first macro, it would be in Module1 and you might have to expand VBAProject and/or Modules folders in the top pane on the left). 
Next, you can add a new sub, you can copy the one below and update the commented lines. I've tested on Access DB only. If connection details recorded with the macro are different that what I have below, leave yours and only change what's needed.

```
Sub RefreshMacro()

Dim myDate As String

    myDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")  'THIS MUST BE YOUR SHEET AND CELL NAMES, ASSUMING DATE VARIABLE IS IN CELL A1
    Range("C1").Select 'ASSUMING OUTPUT IS IN CELL C1
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("testaDB").OLEDBConnection 'THIS MUST BE YOUR CONNECTION, COPY FROM WHAT WAS RECORDED IN THE PREVIOUS STEP, SUB MACRO1
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .CommandText = Array("select * from tbl2_10_15 where ProductDate < #" & myDate & "#;")
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .Connection = Array("OLE...") 'THIS OLE... MUST BE YOUR CONNECTION STRING, COPY FROM WHAT WAS RECORDED IN THE PREVIOUS STEP, SUB MACRO1
        .SourceDataFile = "C:\Users\...testaDB.accdb" 'THIS OLE... MUST BE YOUR CONNECTION STRING, COPY FROM WHAT WAS RECORDED IN THE PREVIOUS STEP, SUB MACRO1
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("testaDB") 'THIS MUST BE YOUR CONNECTION NAME
        .Name = "testaDB"
        .Description = ""
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("testaDB").Refresh 'THIS MUST BE YOUR CONNECTION NAME

End Sub
```

2. Another way would be to "build" the date in SQL, like date() - day(date()) to get the beginning of the month for example. If that's an option, it would be a better solution in my opinion, but I'd need more detail to put this one together. 
   Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for your help, but I am really looking for an sql solution.  plus, i was unable to reproduce {d'2014-01-01'} with myDate string...

Comment: I was working with MS Access db and forgot to format the date for SQL. All you'd need to do is replace the # sings with your format in the VBA query, like this:
.CommandText = Array("SELECT inv.idclient, inv.invnumber, inv.invdate FROM source.invoices inv WHERE inv.idclient = 111222 AND inv.invdate > {d'" & myDate & "'};")

Comment: In SQL, if you have the rights, you could declare a local variable, here's a link to related post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793379/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-sql-server-and-use-it-in-the-same-stored-procedure
If this is ongoing, you could even create a table with the dates needed and link to it in your query.

Comment: Hi! i was finally able to create the string in vba with the date variable...  inv.duedat> {d'" & myDate & " ' " _
        , "}" . Frankly, this is a pain in the ... . About the sql variable declaration, could you confirm that i can do the create procedure inside a odbc excel query? Thank you again!

Comment: Great that it worked. Creating  SQL tables from Excel via odbc should work if you have "create rights", though probably not the best practice. I'd normally create them in MS SQL directly or use the date tables already  there.  I've done global temp table in SQL from Excel to avoid overpopulating the server with accidentally forgotten tables.

Comment: all solved by putting the connection into java. now need to learn javafx OR integrate apache poi...